# Why Java Internal Compiler and IndexOf() returns different index for a String?

Tags: java, string, indexing

My File Contains :

```
public class MyC {
public void MyMethod()
        {
            **System.out.println("My method has been accessed")** // ; is expected

            System.out.println("My method has been accessed");
}
```

}

when I  invoke the Eclipse Compiler on this file, it returns :

```
Code: compiler.err.expected
Kind: ERROR
Line Number: 4
End position: 99
Position: 99
```

However when I try to insert the missing string ";" at Position 99 on line 4, it get "Index out of range exception".

I did count manually in the file and index 99 is not even present in the file. How To fix this issue.

**Here is my Program that Replaces at Specific Positions:**

```
try {



             int num[] = {4}; //Line Numbers

             String[] VALUES = new String[] {";"}; //Correct Solutions

             //String[] VALUES1 = new String[] {"ic"}; //To Replace With

             int [] StartIndex ={99};

             int [] EndIndex ={99};
             FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Antish\\Desktop\\MyC1.java");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

             FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Antish\\Desktop\\Test_File1.txt");

             String line;
             String line1 = null;

             String done = null;
             Integer count =0;

             line = br.readLine();
             count++;

             while(line!=null){


                 boolean exists = false;
                 for(int index =0;index<num.length;index++){
                     if(count == num[index]){ //Line Count Equals



                             exists = true;
                             StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(line);

                             buf.replace(StartIndex[index], EndIndex[index], VALUES[index]);//Get Positions From Array oF Indexes
                             done = buf.toString();
                             writer1.write(done+System.getProperty("line.separator"));



                     }
                 }

                 if (!exists)
                     writer1.write(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                 line = br.readLine();

                 count++;


                 }
```

**when I run the above program , I get this:**

[image]

**The program works fine and does replace strings at specific index. My concern is why Java Compiler is returning such big positions from the file.**

Comment: I guess the indicated position reflects the parser position, even if virtual, not the actual index in the string. The message should probably be read "I expected something at that index but found nothing".

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger so you have a better understanding of what each line does, and it will help you find the bug.

Comment: See: [Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in the tutorial/docs. You seem to be confused regarding syntax.

Comment: @fge - How can i fix this issue then. Is the Compiler also counting empty spaces in the file?

Comment: You do need to understand the difference between compile errors and exceptions. Compiler errors refer to the source code of your program; exceptions refer to the states your program encounters as it executes. There is no reason to expect any number appearing in any compiler error to be the same as any number appearing in an exception message. In other words your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok already found the solution to it..The compiler is reading the file char by char. I modified my replacement codes and now it works. Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
int [] StartIndex ={99};
```

Creates an array with one element that has a value of 99. I am not sure what youa re trying to do, but I think you probably want this instead:

```
int[] StartIndex = new int[99];
```

Comment: ok Done but still index out of range . because index 99 is not even present on that line. Is the Java Compiler also counting empty spaces?